# Count the number of substrings between two markers in a list

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times the name is mentioned in the following list and put the number and frequency mentioned in a dictionary.

so, for example, this is the dialogue list

```
dialogue = ["This is great! RT @user14: Can you believe this?",
            "That's right RT @user22: The dodgers are destined to win the west!",
            "This is about things @user14, how could you",
            "RT @user11: The season is looking great!"]
```

I want my output to be `{user14:2, user22:1, user11:1}`

I have tried to start writing the following to produce a name list and then count the name list and output to the dictionary. But not sure how to do this

```
user_name = [x.split('@')[1].split(':')[:-1] for x in tweets]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably the best approach to account for the unknown characters after the user name:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

result = defaultdict(int)

for item in dialogue:

    user = re.search('(?<=@)[\w\s]+', item).group(0)
    result[user] += 1

print(result)
```

Gives:

```
{'user14': 2, 'user22': 1, 'user11': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

In single pass with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall) function:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

...
uname_counts = Counter(re.findall(r'@(\w+)', ''.join(dialogue)))
print(dict(uname_counts))   # {'user14': 2, 'user22': 1, 'user11': 1}
```